# How to fill a shape with the pattern when generating PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to draw shapes in PDF. Sadly, I can't find any information on filling shapes with a custom pattern, 45-degree stripes in this case.

[Stripes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XoIh.png)

I assume, there is no tool available to do that. How can I achieve the same effect?

Possible solution might be cropping manually drawn lines or using a library that is not PDFsharp, but I am just guessing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Create a path for the shape. Then just fill a rectangle that surrounds the shape with the pattern you need.

See "Clip through path" in the Graphics sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Clip_through_path_16

The sample uses text as a shape, but the path can be anything you can draw.

```
XGraphicsPath path = new XGraphicsPath();
path.AddString("Clip!", new XFontFamily("Verdana"), XFontStyle.Bold, 90, 
    new XRect(0, 0, 250, 140), XStringFormats.Center);

gfx.IntersectClip(path);

// Draw a beam of dotted lines
XPen pen = XPens.DarkRed.Clone();
pen.DashStyle = XDashStyle.Dot;
for (double r = 0; r <= 90; r += 0.5)
    gfx.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 
        250 * Math.Cos(r / 90 * Math.PI), 250 * Math.Sin(r / 90  Math.PI));
```